# Copypaste not working in Visual Studio Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, copy-paste

Copypaste works well in any file of project but not working in Solution explorer.

The paste item appears disabled in menu after right clicking on folder in Solution Explorer. Not dependent on project. Save mode doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Problem disapeared after closing CoolNovo (ChromePlus) browser. I don't know how it was connected so I've turn back to Crome.

Comment: I closed firefox and turn  back to Edge and problem disapeared.

Answer (score 1):

Install VS 2010 Service Pack 1

[Download from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691)

Answer (score 1):

Restart your PC may help. I am facing the same problem just now. My computer had worked for few days, and only this morning Visual Studio has some serious problems like 1) unable to paste file either from file system or within solution. 2) unable to paste even code 3) unable to drag and drop UI component.   Just before I reinstall VS, I restart my computer and all problems gone.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar-SA/vssetup/thread/3b2c7eb5-fd46-41e3-b781-a1853039b630) on MSDN forum about it - several ways are offered for solution. For me worked only Reinstalling/Repairing Visual Studio from 'Control Panel' / 'All Programs'.